# Is there a way to associate an environment with a collection?

Tags: postman

I often switch collections and then remember I didn't switch the environment to correspond to the collection. Is there a way to tie them together, at least for a default?

Comment: Not by default I don’t think but you could add a test to check for a specific value within an environment file and have a visual indicator to know if it’s the right file? Are there things that you could just place in the collection itself?

Comment: I am thinking I should move collection-specific info into collection variables and then use a standard base environment across multiple collections.